# has_any with > 10K values

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We're running into Kusto has_any limit of 10K.
Sample code

```
// Query: Get failed operations for migrated apps
let migrationsTimeDiff = 15d;
let operationsDiffTime = 24h + 1m;
let migratedApps = FirstTable
    | where TimeStamp >= ago(migrationsTimeDiff)
    | where MetricName == "JobSucceeded"
    | project
        MigrationTime = PreciseTimeStamp,
        appName = tostring(parse_json(Annotations).AppName)
    | project appName;
SecondTable
    | where TimeStamp > ago(operationsDiffTime)
    | where Url has_any (appName)
    | where Result == "Fail"
```

Is there a way to restructure the query via joins?
Alternatively is it possible to loop in batches of 10k?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Url` is an exact match to `appName`, then you should use:

```
SecondTable
| where TimeStamp > ago(operationsDiffTime)
| where Url in (appName)   // 'in' instead of 'has_any'
| where Result == "Fail"
```

Otherwise, you'll need to extract the application name from the `Url` using `extend`, and then use `in` like I suggested above, so your query will look like this:

```
SecondTable
| where TimeStamp > ago(operationsDiffTime)
| extend ExtractedAppNameFromUrl = ...
| where ExtractedAppNameFromUrl in (appName)   // 'in' instead of 'has_any'
| where Result == "Fail"
```

Comment: Url isn't an exact match. It is something like https://global-endpoint/appName/api/v1/params . I think the extract approach may work here. Lemme try and get back.

Comment: Try using the the parse operator for the extraction